# NPM getting 404 on installing packages

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to install packages for an angular project based on a template of the customer.
He has provided me this let's say ready to use template, but when I run `npm install` I get errors.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://artifactory.springlab.enel.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-public/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.1102.19' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git URL.
```

As you can see the issue is on a GET from a server of theirs. I have highlighted this issue but they said that is not their fault as they can run npm install without any issue.

Please note that:

- When I run the npm install I'm logged in inside their VPN to access the servers.
- I've tried several versions of node and npm, using the same version that is working on their machines.
- I've tried both `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` and I always get the same error.
- I have no issues on npm in any of the other 10s projects I work on (for other customers)
- I have also disabled the antivirus.

IT support from the company is not providing me with help, so I'm alone and I don't know what to check.
How can I get more details on why I got a 404 on that?

Comment: You can try removing node_module folders and try to re run command again npm i and make sure every angular and related packages are sync with same version too.

Comment: Seems this registry you are using does not contain that package (or that specific version of that package) No option you pass to `npm install` (except for using a different registry) can help you downloading a file, that isn't there. The only one who can help you fix this error is the provider of this registry.  And depending on your project's configuration, maybe you are not even supposed to download "public" (in the sense of available from npmjs.org) packages from their registry, but only their private packages ...

Comment: To make sure the package exists or not, you can enter `npm v @angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.1102.19`